# millis() function output using Serial.print()

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded

This is the code

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(millis());

}
```

This is the output.

> 15:26:28.813 -> 0 15:26:28.813 -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 ->
> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932
> -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 0 15:26:28.932 ->
> 0 15:26:28.932 -> 1 15:26:28.932 -> 1 15:26:28.932 -> 1 15:26:28.932
> -> 1 15:26:28.932 -> 1 15:26:28.932 -> 1 15:26:28.932 -> 1 15:26:28.932 -> 4 15:26:28.932 -> 7 15:26:28.932 -> 10 15:26:28.932 ->
> 14 15:26:28.932 -> 18 15:26:28.932 -> 22 15:26:28.932 -> 26
> 15:26:28.932 -> 30 15:26:28.932 -> 34 15:26:28.932 -> 38 15:26:28.932
> -> 43 15:26:28.932 -> 47 15:26:28.932 -> 51 15:26:28.932 -> 55 15:26:28.959 -> 59 15:26:28.959 -> 64 15:26:28.959 -> 68 15:26:28.959
> -> 72 15:26:28.959 -> 76 15:26:28.959 -> 80 15:26:28.990 -> 84 15:26:28.990 -> 89 15:26:28.990 -> 93 15:26:28.990 -> 97 15:26:28.990
> -> 101 15:26:28.990 -> 106 15:26:28.990 -> 111 15:26:29.029 -> 116 15:26:29.029 -> 121 15:26:29.029 -> 126 15:26:29.029 -> 133
> 15:26:29.029 -> 138 15:26:29.029 -> 143 15:26:29.029 -> 148
> 15:26:29.029 -> 153 15:26:29.064 -> 158 15:26:29.064 -> 163
> 15:26:29.064 -> 168 15:26:29.064 -> 174 15:26:29.064 -> 179
> 15:26:29.064 -> 184 15:26:29.064 -> 189 15:26:29.101 -> 195
> 15:26:29.101 -> 200 15:26:29.101 -> 205 15:26:29.101 -> 210
> 15:26:29.101 -> 216 15:26:29.101 -> 221 15:26:29.101 -> 226
> 15:26:29.136 -> 231 15:26:29.136 -> 236 15:26:29.136 -> 241
> 15:26:29.136 -> 246 15:26:29.136 -> 251 15:26:29.136 -> 257
> 15:26:29.136 -> 263 15:26:29.173 -> 268 15:26:29.173 -> 273
> 15:26:29.173 -> 278 15:26:29.173 -> 283 15:26:29.173 -> 288
> 15:26:29.173 -> 293 15:26:29.173 -> 299 15:26:29.210 -> 304
> 15:26:29.210 -> 309 15:26:29.210 -> 314 15:26:29.210 -> 319
> 15:26:29.210 -> 324 15:26:29.210 -> 330 15:26:29.210 -> 335
> 15:26:29.248 -> 340 15:26:29.248 -> 346 15:26:29.248 -> 351
> 15:26:29.248 -> 356 15:26:29.248 -> 361 15:26:29.248 -> 366
> 15:26:29.248 -> 371 15:26:29.284 -> 376 15:26:29.284 -> 381
> 15:26:29.284 -> 387 15:26:29.284 -> 392 15:26:29.284 -> 398
> 15:26:29.284 -> 403 15:26:29.284 -> 408 15:26:29.320 -> 413
> 15:26:29.320 -> 418 15:26:29.320 -> 423 15:26:29.320 -> 429
> 15:26:29.320 -> 434 15:26:29.320 -> 439 15:26:29.320 -> 444
> 15:26:29.354 -> 449 15:26:29.354 -> 454 15:26:29.354 -> 459
> 15:26:29.354 -> 465 15:26:29.354 -> 471 15:26:29.354 -> 476
> 15:26:29.387 -> 481 15:26:29.387 -> 486 15:26:29.387 -> 491
> 15:26:29.387 -> 496 15:26:29.387 -> 501 15:26:29.387 -> 506
> 15:26:29.387 -> 512 15:26:29.422 -> 517 15:26:29.422 -> 522
> 15:26:29.422 -> 528 15:26:29.422 -> 533 15:26:29.422 -> 538
> 15:26:29.422 -> 543 15:26:29.422 -> 548 15:26:29.456 -> 553
> 15:26:29.456 -> 559 15:26:29.456 -> 564 15:26:29.456 -> 569
> 15:26:29.456 -> 574 15:26:29.456 -> 579 15:26:29.492 -> 584
> 15:26:29.492 -> 589 15:26:29.492 -> 595 15:26:29.492 -> 601
> 15:26:29.492 -> 606 15:26:29.492 -> 611 15:26:29.492 -> 616
> 15:26:29.529 -> 621 15:26:29.529 -> 626 15:26:29.529 -> 631
> 15:26:29.529 -> 636 15:26:29.529 -> 642 15:26:29.529 -> 647
> 15:26:29.529 -> 652 15:26:29.567 -> 657 15:26:29.567 -> 663
> 15:26:29.567 -> 668 15:26:29.567 -> 673 15:26:29.567 -> 678
> 15:26:29.567 -> 684 15:26:29.567 -> 689 15:26:29.602 -> 694
> 15:26:29.602 -> 699 15:26:29.602 -> 704 15:26:29.602 -> 709
> 15:26:29.602 -> 714 15:26:29.602 -> 719 15:26:29.602 -> 724
> 15:26:29.638 -> 731 15:26:29.638 -> 736 15:26:29.638 -> 741
> 15:26:29.638 -> 746 15:26:29.638 -> 751 15:26:29.638 -> 756
> 15:26:29.638 -> 761 15:26:29.672 -> 766 15:26:29.672 -> 772
> 15:26:29.672 -> 777 15:26:29.672 -> 782 15:26:29.672 -> 787
> 15:26:29.672 -> 792 15:26:29.672 -> 798 15:26:29.706 -> 803
> 15:26:29.706 -> 808 15:26:29.706 -> 814 15:26:29.706 -> 819
> 15:26:29.706 -> 824 15:26:29.706 -> 829 15:26:29.742 -> 834
> 15:26:29.742 -> 839 15:26:29.742 -> 844 15:26:29.742 -> 849
> 15:26:29.742 -> 855

I am trying to develop an algorithm with and without using a giant array to store 3-Axis acceleration data to calculate distance travelled on either axis.
Is this the most accurate timing I can get from and Arduino?
This output is not at all accurate.
Am I using it wrong?
Why is this timing output after these intervals?
Where can I find out more about this?

Comment: `This output is not at all accurate` read about "buffering"

Comment: @KamilCuk Can you please suggest a few more keywords to put in google along with buffeering?

Comment: Like "arduino Serial buffer print" but learning about "standard C buffering modes" would be also advised. The [note here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/write/).

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Please post the text as text into your question. Take a [tour].

Comment: You could learn all about buffering but that would only answer the question of why your test is flawed, which is not the question you have asked - don't get distracted, but be aware that the take home here is that you should not try to output your results at the same time you are collecting your time-critical data, because the output will dominate the timing.  This is really an X-Y problem; you would do better perhaps to describe your system and ask about how to do the distance calculation, (and perhaps output the result without affecting that calculation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this the most accurate timing I can get from and Arduino?

There is also `micros()`. Note that accuracy is not resolution.

> Am I using it wrong?

No.

> Why is this timing output after these intervals?

The output of `millis()` is just put in internal buffer. In *pseudocode* it works generally like so:

```
char internal_buffer[SOME_SIZE];
void Serial::println(SOME_TYPE stuff) {
     if (internal_buffer_is_full()) {
          // actively wait for at least space for stuff to place
          internal_buffer_wait_for_space_for_stuff(stuff);
     }
     internal_buffer += stuff; // just add the data to internal buffer
     if (!hardware::is_writing()) {
           hardware::start_writing(internal_buffer); // writes __asynchronously__!
     }
}
```

First it's all buffered. Then **asynchronously** the buffer is written to output and the main thread continues it's operation. When the buffer is full, then the main thread actively waits for at least some space in the buffer before putting the data to be written in to the buffer. It's expected that you'll see short "flushes" where the **buffered** output is outputted a little bit then the buffering continues.

There is `Serial.flush()` if you want to flush buffered data.

Comment: Where can I find more about this? Are the Arduino drivers open-source?

Comment: Yes they are. And arduino has understandable and enormous (compared to other projects...) documentation. Pro tip: write in google something with "github", like "arduino github", and 99% of the time [you'll find the sources](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino). [Here is implementation of AVR hardwareserial](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L225), looks like a simple circular buffer.

Comment: where can I study more about things like circular Buffer which subject is this from?@KamilCuk

Comment: Well, I believe further study are books, then more books and tutorials. There is a list of good C and C++ books on stackoverflow. Then further study is going to university. Circular buffers as I remember are explained on wiki too.

Comment: It is not quite as simple as that, and that is not even the primary cause of the timing issues in the OPs test.  The UART serial output feeds the input of the UART of the the serial-USB interface (and FTDI chip or separate AVR), that also has buffering and the USB transactions are simplex master-slave in nature and dependent on the host for timing.  Then the serial data ends up on the hose computer with a general purpose non-realtime OS, adding more buffering and even less determinism.

Answer (score 0):

Your your test is dominated by the performance, granularity and of non-deterministic timing of the USB serial communication, rather than the precision of millis() - also the timing is provided by the connected PC which not being a real-time system and having its own buffering behaviour will only add another variable.

Both `millis()` and `micros()` are as accurate as the clock source on your board, a typical crystal oscillator is good to about 50ppm or 0.005%, a ceramic resonator perhaps 0.5%, while a typical TCXO will be around 2ppm(0.0002%).

Any code executed between calling these functions takes time, and operations such as `println()` outputting to the USB CDC/ACM serial and captured on a PC will be particularly non-deterministic.

If you really want to confirm the precision you should use a faster and more deterministic output such as a digital IO, and scope the pin.  E.g:

```
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite( 2, millis() & 1 ) ;
}
```

That will toggle the pin at 500Hz with a 1:1 duty-cycle (1ms low : 1ms high)

Comment: Dependent on the host for timing? What? Where can I read more about this? How is that even possible the Arduino has it's own flash memory right?

Comment: @ShridharSharma I am not sure you can "read about it" in one single place, 30 years experience in real-time systems development informs my assessment.. It is the consequence of a combination of factors: The manner USB works and how it is fundamentally different than serial port that in this case it is emulating, the fact that the host is not a real-time OS, and the fact that there is more software and buffering operating on the host in order to implement the virtual COM port than is running on the target.

Comment: Your timestamps are provided by the host and are a measure of timing of the combination of the target and the host execution not a direct measure of millis().  I am not sure why you think the Arduino having its own flash memory is relevant to this issue.

Comment: this is one rabbit hole I wanna go down. Thank God I chose Embeded Systems. Any tools you may suggest that I may play around with so I can understand these protocols better. eg Logic analyzer, DSO or anything else?

Comment: @ShridharSharma Well to start with the Arduino software framework is designed to hide all that complexity from you and critically lacks any kind of debugger.  It is rather limited in its capability.  If you want to get into that sort of detail, you'll probably want to _graduate_ from Arduino.  Running mbed on an ST Nucleo board is an obvious step.  With the "offline" mbed developer studio, you get debug capability, Nucleo boards include STLink on-chip debug support, and have Arduino Shield compatible I/O connectors.  The mbed framework includes and RTOS and a "bare-metal" profile.

Comment: @ShridharSharma Ultimately however, SO is not a discussion forum.  You either need to ask separate questions rather then continuing a conversation in comments, or use some other resource, such as https://forum.arduino.cc/, https://os.mbed.com/forum/, or if you want to use your Arduino AVR based hardware with or without the Arduino software framework:: https://www.avrfreaks.net/

Comment: @ShridharSharma With respect to test equipment if you are on a budget and short of space, a PicoScope  is a useful piece of kit, combining DSO, Logic Analyser, Spectrum analyser and function generator capabilities.  Other similar PC scope brands are available such as Hantek.